# Should I use my domain registrar's nameserver or find an alternative?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, nameserver

I've recently been moving my client's sites as well as my own and my friends to a cloud server instance I've set up. I don't have a nameserver setup on my instance because I'm not sure how to deploy and manage that side of things yet.

I'm using the default nameservers where possible for the sites and just changing the A record DNS settings to point at the server. Some clients are complaining that the sites are running slower then before (since I changed nameservers back to the defaults). Some of the domain registrars are a nightmare to deal with and I can't convince some of my clients to leave them.

Is there a sort of paid service I can use instead?

Comment: I should add that I've found the following services too: http://www.namecheap.com/products/freedns.aspx and https://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/custom/

Comment: I also found out that godaddy have a cheap paid for service too http://www.godaddy.com/domains/dns-hosting.aspx?ci=42422

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ZoneEdit](http://zoneedit.com/) is excellent and your first two DNS zones are free